# Excel Sumifs searching first 8 characters of a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Good evening all,

I want to do a sumifs() but the two columns do not always have the exact same values.  However, the first 8 characters would always match in both columns.  For example the value I wish to look up is "00123456 - Nice Salad". The data I wish to search in sits in Column A with value to return in Column B.

[image]

I know I can use the left() function on the value to lookup but I am unsure how best to search against just the first 8 characters in column A.  I would like the formula to return the number 6 from column B in this example.

Current formula is as follows:  =sumifs(left(00123456 - Nice Salad,8),A:A,B:B)

I hope this all makes sense and any help is appreciated.

Many thanks, Alan.

Comment: `=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,"00123456*")`

Comment: simple... yet genius... worth putting as an answer to help someone in future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Screenshot/[this](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j962SgWrIik5ZJDPRA?e=CJhSpp) sheet refer:

One way is with a regular sum equation:

```
=SUM(1*(LEFT(A2:A4,8)=E2)*(B2:B4))
```

However, this can be computationally intensive (i.e. if you have plenty of data/rows to evaluate).  The better, in  my view, is simply a sumifs with wildcard '*', i.e.:

```
=SUMIFS(B2:B4,A2:A4,E2&"*")
```

[image: Sum vs sumifs]

Comment: Is there a way to do the same concept with an xlookup?

Comment: Hi @Alan Tingey - perhaps someone else is wiser re: xlookups but from what I know it can return arrays, and can work with wildcards (so would seem there is hope..) but cannot distinguish between multiple 'common values' - i.e. arrays only return when the lookup values are distinct/unique.  Some brief experimentation on my part substantiates this - so, unless I'm unaware of some nifty 'trick' - I'd say 'not easily'... See here for a useful vid on xlookups:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ViMm-wuM3U